# Activity with DatePicker and TimePicker with Holo Light style

Tags: android, datepicker, styles, timepicker

I'm trying to do a Transparent Activity, with a custom layout containing A DatePicker and a Time Picker side by side,
The activity should be transparent and dimmed, while the DatePicker and TimePicker should be with Holo.Light style.

the only way i got it to work was theming the activity with Holo.Dialog which prevents me from displaying the container in fill_parent.

The trouble is, that i can't seem to find the right style, event tried a custom style with Holo.Light as the parent style.

any suggestions ?

thanks

Comment: this is the code for the custom style derived from Holo.Light:

  <style name="Theme.TFM_Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>        
    
    </style>

Comment: I have no idea.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the issue by expanding from Holo.Light like so:

```
  <style name="Theme.Translucent.Pickers" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```